# Generating the same sequence of random number in a loop

Tags: c

A for loop to be exact. I've tried using srand() to seed the loop but it doesn't seem to be working. Could someone clarify the seeding part? Anyways, could someone point out my errors?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int a,b,c,d,loop1=0,loop2=1,count=0;
    srand(1);
    while(loop1!=1)
   {
        a=rand()%10;
        b=rand()%10;
        c=rand()%10;
        d=rand()%10;
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a,b,c,d);
        count+=1;
        if (count>3)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

return 0;        
}
```

The output should look like this:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Move the call to `srand` inside the loop at the beginning.

Comment: @cswannabe: please edit your question with the text "What if I want to generate the same sequence of numbers for the current run but when I restart my program, a new sequence is generated and preserved for that run". That makes any solution very different.

Comment: Please read the documentation for rand and srand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the seed at the beginning of the loop if you want to have the same sequence in each iteration:

```
while(loop1!=1) {
    srand(1);
    a=rand()%10;
    b=rand()%10;
    c=rand()%10;
    d=rand()%10;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a,b,c,d);
    count+=1;
    if (count>3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to generate the same sequence of numbers for the current run but when I restart my program, a new sequence is generated and preserved for that run?

Comment: @cswannabe ... then you need to seed with a different value at each run, for example like this: `srand(1)` -> `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));`

Comment: Not clear, you want a new sequence on each run? Then use different seed. The common trick is to get the current time and use it to feed the generator, something like `srand(time())`, or use the pid : `srand(getpid())` (more probability to get the same sequence).

Comment: Note that only the debug version of randomizers generally behave determinisitc (i.e. generate the same sequence with the same seed). Non-debug versions are often more truely random (i.e. non-deterministic).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie are you sure ? I don't know what the standard says though...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Wrong! srand, srandom, etc are all designed to get the exact same sequence if the same seed is used. If not, how to reproduce tests? `Like rand(3), random() will by default produce a sequence of
     numbers that can be duplicated by calling srandom() with the same seed`

Comment: @cswannabe do you want this behavior, http://rextester.com/UVBOG29961 ? your question need to be clarified

Comment: POSIX says: `If srand() is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated.`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, I see...it means that `rand()` is vulnerable and cryptographically insecure: a hacker, knowing the random number generator (algorithm and tables) and the time when seeding, can devise the random number sequence generated by the random number generator. MS provides `rand_s()` which it claims is cryptographically secure.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes rand/random, etc are not designed for cryptographic purposes. This is another much harder problem.